# Wait for context value to load before making an API call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a user context that loads the user data. I am using that data to send API requests in `useEffect`. The time lag in the loading of the data is causing an undefined variable in my API request. How do I make the useEffect wait for the context variable to load before sending the request?

This is the UserContext.js:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext({});

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default UserContext;
```

This is the custom hook:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import UserContext from "../context/UserProvider";

const useUser = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};

export default useUser;
```

And this is the API call in the profile page:

```
  const { user } = useUser();

  useEffect(() => {

    Axios.get(
      `API_URL/${user?.subscription_id}`
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    });

  }, []);
```

How can I ensure user data is loaded before I make a request throughout my app?

Answer (score 1):

In react, Context APi static data will be Passed to the Children at initial Load. But if you are using asynchronous data in context api, you have to use useEffect and add context value as dependency..

```
export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  // Updating Context value Asynchronously..
  setTimeout(() => {
    setUser("data");
  }, [3000]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
  const { user } = useUser();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Call api only if user contains data.
    if(user != {}) {
      Axios.get(
      `API_URL/${user?.subscription_id}`
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    });
    }
  }, [user]);
```

Comment: I am updating the user data in my App.js on every call to retain the user session